# How to reload a javascript function and reload a footer on html page without reloading the whole page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a main.page.php that loads a javascript funtion to get a server up or down status.
i would like to reload this function every 10 seconds to check the server status and update the status message in footer div by refreshing the footer not the whole page.

main.page.php

```
<head>

<?php require_once 'inc/meta.php'; ?>

<?php require_once 'inc/css.php'; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">

    'use strict';

    function queryPlex (query) {
          return $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'inc/plex-api.php',
          cache: false,
          data: {'postData': query},
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
          getServerStatus();   
    });

    function getServerStatus () {

         const serverStatusDiv = $('#server-status-msg'); 
         const getServerStatus = queryPlex('/');
         getServerStatus.done(function (data) {
                 if (data) {     
                 serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:green; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;ONLINE <span style="color:green;" class="fas fa-fw fa-check-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                } else {     
                 serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:red; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;OFFLINE <span style="color:red;" class="fas fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                }
            });

         getServerStatus.fail(function () {  
         serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:red; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;OFFLINE <span style="color:red;" class="fas fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                    });    
}
   </script>

</head>

<body id="body_iframe"  onload="getServerStatus ()">

<!-- ============ Fixed Nav ============ -->

     <?php require_once 'inc/nav_main.php'; ?>

<!-- ============ Begin page content ============= -->


    <div id="container_iframe" style="background-color:black;">
          <iframe id="iframe" name="frame" frameBorder="0" scrollbar="no" src="./?page=media"></iframe>
        </div>


<!-- ============ Sticky Footer ============ -->

    <?php require_once 'inc/footer.php'; ?>

<!-- ============== Bootstrap core JavaScript  ================= -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php require_once 'inc/javascripts.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

footer.php

```
<!-- ============ Footer ============ -->

<div id="footer_iframe" class="bg-black">
  <div class="text-right">

    <!-- ============ Check Server Status ============ -->

    <p class="text-right">StreamNet Server: <span id="server-status-msg">&nbsp;checking status ....</span></p>  


  </div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

i updated my main.page.php

added `setTimout` to the function an added script to reload the footer div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    'use strict';

    function queryPlex (query) {
          return $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'inc/plex-api.php',
          cache: false,
          data: {'postData': query},
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
          getServerStatus();   
    });

    function getServerStatus () {

         const serverStatusDiv = $('#server-status-msg'); 
         const getServerStatus = queryPlex('/');
         getServerStatus.done(function (data) {
                 if (data) {     
                 serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:green; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;ONLINE <span style="color:green;" class="fas fa-fw fa-check-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                } else {     
                 serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:red; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;OFFLINE <span style="color:red;" class="fas fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                }
            });

         getServerStatus.fail(function () {  
         serverStatusDiv.html(' <i style="color:red; font-style:normal;"> &nbsp;OFFLINE <span style="color:red;" class="fas fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle" data-fa-transform="grow-4"></span></i>');
                    }); 

      setTimeout(getServerStatus, 10000);

}
   </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#footer").load('inc/footer.php')
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

also i removed the php code to load the footer.php at the end of the main.page.php.

```
<body id="body_iframe"  onload="getServerStatus ()">

<!-- ============ Fixed Nav ============ -->

     <?php require_once 'inc/nav_main.php'; ?>

<!-- ============ Begin page content ============= -->


    <div id="container_iframe" style="background-color:black;">
          <iframe id="iframe" name="frame" frameBorder="0" scrollbar="no" src="./?page=media"></iframe>
        </div>


<!-- ============ Sticky Footer ============ -->
<div id="footer"></div>


<!-- ============== Bootstrap core JavaScript  ================= -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php require_once 'inc/javascripts.php'; ?>

</body>
```

but now my footer isn't loading anymore?

Comment: With a recursive [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) call.

Comment: will it be possible to show me how to achieve this? please

Comment: We generally expect that before you post, you'll do exhaustive research on your question and make an attempt at a solution. Then, if you have questions/problems with your attempt that you'll post them here. For now, you should take the time to investigate the links I've shared and then use that information to make an attempt of your own.

Comment: allright, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setInterval

setInterval(getServerStatus, 10000);

[setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

And for the footer, you can just replace the content using jQuery.

```
$('#server-status-msg').html('Server is Up');
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. but this wouldnt reload the footer div without reloading the whole content.

Comment: We generally expect that before someone posts, they'll do exhaustive research on their question and make an attempt at a solution. Then, if they have questions/problems with the attempt, they'll post them here.

Comment: You can reload whatever part of the footer you need, without reloading the whole content, with jQuery. Is your page reloading anything more than the footer?

Comment: @nicoavn yes by reloading the page it will change the last log-in date of the user.